# Chrome - Only view network activity for "main page" in Dev Tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When I load a page in Chrome, and view it in "Chrome Dev Tools | Network", I see the network activity for the page I loaded, and all child resources that are loaded by the page.

Is there anyway I can just view the network activity for the url that's loaded in the address bar ?

For example, If I typed in "google.com" in the address bar, I'd like to see just the redirects it does, not the child resources of the page.

Comment: Click `Doc` in the network toolbar? And maybe `[x] Preserve log` to keep the log on navigations?

Comment: Good point - and `Doc` nearly does it, but it hides all the redirects that are happening in between. So for example, if I loaded a page, and it redirected 20 times, `Doc` only shows one entry in the network history, from my experience. I want to see those 20 redirects for just the url that's happening as the main url in the address bar.

Comment: Those redirects aren't exposed, apparently. I'd use an external inspector like Fiddler or Wireshark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The best answer I've found is to:

- Show the "Priority" column in the "Network Inspector" by right clicking on the Network inspector header and choosing "Priority"
- Filter by "priority:Highest"

This includes redirects as well. It also includes other super important requests, but it's the best I've found so far.